# change the width of dimple js chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am working with dimple js and I want to change the width of chart and redraw it again how can I do this. I tried `chart.width()` and even `chart.newSvg()` but these came to nothing I have sample `javascript` line chart and I put it in `jsfiddle`
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmhwvzwm/)
Javascript Code:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 400),
            data = [
                { "Value" : 10, "Year" : 2009 },
                { "Value" : 5, "Year" : 2010 },
                { "Value" : 4, "Year" : 2011 },
                { "Value" : 7, "Year" : 2012 },
                { "Value" : 10, "Year" : 2010 },
                { "Value" : 50, "Year" : 2020 },
                { "Value" : 40, "Year" : 2015 },
                { "Value" : 100, "Year" : 2014 },
                { "Value" : 200, "Year" : 2014 }
            ];
    var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Year");
    x.addOrderRule("Year");
    var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Value");
    chart.addColorAxis("Value", ["green", "yellow", "red"]);
    var lines = chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
    lines.lineWeight = 4;
    lines.lineMarkers = true;
    chart.ease = "bounce";
    chart.staggerDraw = true;
    chart.draw(2000);
```

Comment: can you put it on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Hardik Anavadia http://jsfiddle.net/mmhwvzwm/

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmhwvzwm/2)

Change this

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 400),
```

to your required width

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", width, height),
```

And use this line before plotting chart again

```
 document.getElementById('').innerHTML="";
```

Comment: I can't get your answer I just want to change the width of chart and redraw it again I don't want to declare another chart and put it instead of this

Comment: i just gave you two chart for example .
you can just change width by replacing 600 with your required width.
and before redraw remove innerHTML of a DIV simple.

Comment: It wasn't my question I just want to change the width and redraw that chart again not declare another one